# Xcode basics: Declare custom class with integer properties and use it in another class

Tags: xcode, class, properties, integer

Trying to do something really simple, but can't figure out the syntax.

I have a class called Word.h which has 8 properties, strings and integers. For the sake of keeping things simple, I'll stick to 2 here:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface Word : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *word; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *wordLevel;
@end
```

Both properties are synthesised in the .m file

I then want to create some objects in another file (UIViewController). In the .h file I have this:

```
#import "Word.h"
```

and in the .m file, this:

```
Word *newWord = [[Word alloc] init];
   [newWord setWord:@"theorise"];
   [newWord setWordLevel:6];

Word *newWord1 = [[Word alloc] init];
   [newWord setWord:@"implicit"];
   [newWord setWordLevel:7];

Word *newWord2 = [[Word alloc] init];
   [newWord setWord:@"incredible"];
   [newWord setWordLevel:9];
```

I now get an error message "Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSNumber *' is disallowed with ARC"

What am I doing wrong...is the property defined incorrectly in the class file?? How do I access this property. It works fine with the string.

I will also want to access the properties later - how do I do that...for example:

```
cell.label1.text = [newWord2 wordLevel];
```

Is this the right syntax???

Hoping someone can help me, tearing clumps of hair out here!
M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `wordLevel` to be an `NSNumber`, an object. You are treating it in your code like it is a plain C `int`. You have to decide which your want it to be and treat it that way consistently. For example, for a plain C `int` property you would instead declare:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int wordLevel;
```

On the other hand if you really want `wordLevel` to be an `NSNumber` you need to use the setter like this:

```
[newWord setWordLevel:[NSNumber numberWithInt:6]];
```